# Which version of fabric API is installed

Tags: python, fabric

How might I discover which version of fabric I have installed - through the API?

I understand that I can just run

```
$ fab --version
```

but I'd rather be doing something like

```
>>> import fabric
>>> fabric.version
'1.4.1'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the version submodule in fabric:

```
>>>import fabric.version
>>>fabric.version.get_version()
'1.2.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to even do that, it's in the [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/env.html?highlight=version#version):

```
from fabric.api import *
print env.version
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly with Fabric 2 you have now to do something like

```
import fabric
if hasattr(fabric, '__version__'):
    # For fabric2
    print(fabric.__version_info__)
    print(fabric.__version__)   # for a version tuple
else:
    # for fabric1
    from fabric.api import *
    print(env.version)
```